# pyodbc with MS Access expecting too many parameters

Tags: sql, python-3.x, ms-access, pyodbc

I am trying to query an Access DB for results in a certain timeframe. As I am querying, I would like to automagically add a column to the output specifying which week (from a range of weeks) the data belongs to. The automagic column is generated by passing a parameter to the select statement. I keep going back and forth between two errors and I can't figure out why.

ERROR 1) Too few parameters.

ERROR 2) Syntax error in JOIN

My python code:

ERROR 1 Code:

```
qry = '''
    SELECT [PreQuery].[defect], SUM([PreQuery].[qty_rej] + [PreQuery].[qty_rew]) AS [qty_defect], ? AS [wk_no]
    FROM (
        SELECT [Sort].[Date of Sort] AS [srt_date], [Part].[Part Name] AS [prt_no], [Defect Table].[Defect2] AS [defect], [Defect Table].[Quantity Rejected] AS [qty_rej], [Defect Table].[Quantity Reworked] AS [qty_rew]
        FROM (([Defect Table] LEFT JOIN [Sort] ON [Defect Table].[Sort Number] = [Sort].[Sort Number]) LEFT JOIN [Part] ON [Sort].[Part Number] = [Part].[Part Number])) AS PreQuery LEFT JOIN [Defects] ON [Defects].[Defect Code] = [PreQuery].[Defect2]
    WHERE (([Sort].[Date of Sort] BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND ([Part].[Part Name] LIKE ? & '_TZ______'))
    GROUP BY [defect], [wk_no];'''
```

Raises the following error:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 8. (-3010) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Removing the aliases from [Sort].[Date of Sort] and [Part].[Part Name] reproduces the same error except the driver expects **6** parameters instead of **8** as before. In either case, there are only four **?**s in the whole statement so the DB should be expecting 4 params.

ERROR 2 Code:

```
qry = '''
    SELECT ? AS [wk_no], [defect], SUM([qty_rej] + [qty_rew]) AS [qty_defect]
    FROM (
        SELECT [Sort].[Date of Sort], [Part].[Part Name], [Defect Table].[Defect2] AS [defect], [Defect Table].[Quantity Rejected] AS [qty_rej], [Defect Table].[Quantity Reworked] AS [qty_rew]
        FROM (([Defect Table] LEFT JOIN [Sort] ON [Defect Table].[Sort Number] = [Sort].[Sort Number])
        LEFT JOIN [Part] ON [Sort].[Part Number] = [Part].[Part Number]))
    LEFT JOIN [Defects] ON [Defects].[Defect Code] = [Defect Table].[Defect2]
    WHERE (([Sort].[Date of Sort] BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND ([Part].[Part Name] LIKE ? & '_TZ______'))
    GROUP BY [defect], [wk_no];'''
```

This raises:

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in JOIN operation. (-3510) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

I checked the inner select statement by itself and it executes perfectly fine in either case. Furthermore I couldn't see any obvious syntax errors (and neither could PyCharm checking with MySQL dialect).

Comment: On your second error, I think the subquery needs to be given an alias.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't need all those square brackets. Access only needs them if the column name contains a space. If any of the columns don't exist in the Access DB the item in square brackets will be treated like a parameter. So if possible, I'd  remove the spaces from the field/table names and remove  all the square brackets from the query string.

Comment: @SteveLovell - Identifiers that are not recognized as column names will be treated as parameter names regardless of whether they are enclosed in square brackets. Removing the square brackets is not necessary.

Comment: If the SQL interpreter says you have a syntax error, then you have a syntax error. Whatever PyCharm might say. On that subject, *the interpreter is always right.*

Comment: Thank you all for your responses! Sorry I have not been back here in a while. I added the brackets in an attempt to weed out any potential naming errors.

Answer (score 1):

Overall, there are several issues among both query attempts:

1. Concatenate the literal `'_TZ______'` to your last parameter value as the placeholder, `?`,  must stand on its own.
2. You need to assign a table alias to derived table, *PreQuery*, like you did in first query.
3. The `JOIN` must be on the new column alias, *defect*, not *Defect2*.
4. Move `WHERE` clause inside subquery.
5. Remove the *wk_no* in `GROUP BY` as it is not an actual field. Constants do not need `GROUP BY`.

Consider below syntax adjustment using table aliases for reduced length and readability. Of course without data, I cannot adequately test. Hence, you may need to adjust further:

```
qry = """
    SELECT ? AS [wk_no], [defect], SUM([qty_rej] + [qty_rew]) AS [qty_defect]
    FROM
      (
        SELECT s.[Date of Sort], p.[Part Name], d.[Defect2] AS [defect], 
               d.[Quantity Rejected] AS [qty_rej], d.[Quantity Reworked] AS [qty_rew]
        FROM (([Defect Table] d LEFT JOIN [Sort] s ON d.[Sort Number] = s.[Sort Number])
               LEFT JOIN [Part] p ON s.[Part Number] = p.[Part Number])
        WHERE ((s.[Date of Sort] BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND (p.[Part Name] LIKE ?))
      ) As PreQuery
    LEFT JOIN [Defects] ON [Defects].[Defect Code] = [PreQuery].[defect]        
    GROUP BY [defect];
"""   

cursor.execute(qry, myparams)  # WHERE LAST PARAM HAS '_TZ______' CONCATENATED TO ORIG VALUE
```

Comment: *"the placeholder, `?`, must stand on its own"* - That is actually not required. String parameters can in fact be used as part of a string expression in the SQL command text.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will implement your suggestions and report back with results.

Comment: You are missing an opening parenthesis in `FROM ... JOIN` section. Count to see. Access SQL is stringent on parentheses to enclose table pairings unlike other dialects. Beginners should build query inside the MSAccess.exe GUI program with design builder.